# DNS lookup from dokku container

Tags: node.js, docker, dns, dokku

I'm running a node app inside a dokku container on an Ubuntu server, which also runs `bind9` for DNS. In the node app, I'm running express. On the node app, I'm running a DNS reverse lookup on the client's IP like this (simplified):

```js
const dns = require('dns');
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/myhostname', (req, res) => {
  dns.reverse(req.headers['x-forwarded-for'], (err, hostnames) => {
    res.json({ hostname: hostnames[0] });
  });
});
```

This works fine locally, but once deployed to the dokku container, fails with an `ENOTFOUND` error. Presumably this is because the app isn't set to use the Ubuntu server as its DNS server. So I tried this right after `require('dns')`:

`dns.setServers([process.env.DNS_SERVERS])`

where `DNS_SERVERS` is set to either the local LAN ip of the server, or its docker internal IP. Either of those addresses results in a delay and eventual timeout trying to get the address.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Is bind configured to listen on the IP which the Ubuntu server has on the docker bridge? Have you tried using the `--dns` [argument to docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/) (and providing the IP of the Ubuntu server's Docker bridge)?

Comment: Thanks. Your comment helped me find the solution, which I'll write as an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was this:

- Set `DNS_SERVERS=172.17.0.1`
- Allow requests through the firewall on the `docker0` interface
- Make sure `bind` is listening on 172.17.0.1 *and* that it is set to allow requests from the `172.17.0.0/16` range

The second item on the list is what I wasn't considering...